# Can native applications make use of OS SSO login information?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, single-sign-on, kerberos

If a user logs in to their computer using a Single Sign-On system such as Active Directory, LDAP, or Kerberos, is it possible for applications they run to know who they are and what system they authenticated with?  Can I get enough information out of these systems to verify their identity without requiring any additional user input?

Specifically, I would like to be able to check these things:

- Did they log in via a single sign-on system at all, or are they just using a regular user account on this machine?
- What system did they use?
- Does the system have some URI that would distinguish it from any other directory?
- What is the current user's distinguished name in that directory?
- Can I get some information which I can pass to another host to prove to that host that the user is who they said they are?  For example, a token that can be used to query the SSO system.

I'd assume all of these things should be possible, and in fact encouraged, but I am not positive.  I'm sure the method of getting at this information is

Answer (score 1):

SSO (at least with Kerberos which is used by ActiveDirectoy) is based on a token. As soon as the user requests access to a kerberized system the system queries for the token and checks its validity for accessing the system. It's as good as querying for username and password. when the user did not log in with an Kerberos-account there is no tiket so no automated access.

using the token you can get the users login- name and from that you can then use that to query the SSO-backend (typically LDAP) for more information on that user.

LDAP is not an SSO-system as it is simply a storage query protocol but it is often used as backend for SSO-systems.

The problem often is kerberizing an application. for Webapps that means you have to kerberize the webserver so that that one then can handle the authentication process with the SSO-service and then pass that information on to the unferlying webapp.

Hope that answers you questions.

for more information have a look around the web for kerberos

Comment: I'd like to know how to do the first step.  After a user logs in and starts my application, how can I get their kerberos token?

Answer (score 0):

You are really asking about two things:

Authentication: Who are you?

Authorization: What are you allowed to do?

Kerberos really only answers the first question, you need a secondary system like LDAP or Active Directory ( which is both kerberos and ldap in a single server) to answer the second.

If your system is using kerberos correctly, any user login should have an associated kerberos ticket. With this ticket, you can request "service" tickets
to prove your identity to remote servers that support kerberos. The ticket 
contains your principal identity in the realm ( user@DOMAIN.NET ) that can be
used to query authorization systems.

However, the details required to get all the moving parts in that sentence working together "on the same page" so to speak can be very complex. The remote service has to support accepting kerberos credentials, it has to be either in the same realm or have a cross realm trust relationship configured.... The list
gets pretty long. Depending on your exact application environment, using all these things can be fairly trivial, or it can be next to impossible.

Comment: I'd like to know how to do the first step.  After a user logs in and starts my application, how can I get their kerberos token?

Comment: The kerberos API will take care of that for you when your application attempts to contact a kerberized service. If you want to know the API calls for examining a ticket, look into the source code for klist.